# cabal install fpco-api error

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Recently I tried to install fpco-api on OS X 10.9 via cabal install, but got errors during the building phase. Here is the list of error:

```
... lots of 'loading package'
Loading package asn1-data-0.7.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package asn1-types-0.2.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package crypto-pubkey-types-0.4.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package pem-0.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package certificate-1.3.9 ... linking ... done.
Loading package publicsuffixlist-0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package regex-base-0.93.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package regex-posix-0.95.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package regex-compat-0.95.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package socks-0.5.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package crypto-numbers-0.2.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package crypto-pubkey-0.2.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package tls-1.1.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package cipher-rc4-0.1.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package tls-extra-0.6.6 ... linking ... done.
Loading package http-conduit-1.9.6 ... linking ... done.
Loading package hslogger-1.2.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package MissingH-1.2.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package ConfigFile-1.1.1 ... linking ... done.
[ 5 of 10] Compiling FP.API.Run ( src/library/FP/API/Run.hs, dist/build/FP/API/Run.o )

src/library/FP/API/Run.hs:37:1: Warning:
Module `Prelude' does not export `catch'
[ 6 of 10] Compiling FP.API.TH ( src/library/FP/API/TH.hs, dist/build/FP/API/TH.o )
[ 7 of 10] Compiling FP.Server.Types ( src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs, dist/build/FP/Server/Types.o )

src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:97:36:
Ambiguous occurrence `Loc'
It could refer to either `FP.Server.Types.Loc',
defined at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:115:6
or `Control.Monad.Logger.Loc',
imported from `Control.Monad.Logger' at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:18:1-27
(and originally defined in `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax')

src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:102:46:
Ambiguous occurrence `Loc'
It could refer to either `FP.Server.Types.Loc',
defined at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:115:6
or `Control.Monad.Logger.Loc',
imported from `Control.Monad.Logger' at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:18:1-27
(and originally defined in `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax')

src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:103:46:
Ambiguous occurrence `Loc'
It could refer to either `FP.Server.Types.Loc',
defined at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:115:6
or `Control.Monad.Logger.Loc',
imported from `Control.Monad.Logger' at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:18:1-27
(and originally defined in `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax')

src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:118:17:
Ambiguous occurrence `Loc'
It could refer to either `FP.Server.Types.Loc',
defined at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:115:6
or `Control.Monad.Logger.Loc',
imported from `Control.Monad.Logger' at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:18:1-27
(and originally defined in `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax')

src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:119:19:
Ambiguous occurrence `Loc'
It could refer to either `FP.Server.Types.Loc',
defined at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:115:6
or `Control.Monad.Logger.Loc',
imported from `Control.Monad.Logger' at src/library/FP/Server/Types.hs:18:1-27
(and originally defined in `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax')
Failed to install fpco-api-1.0.5
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
fpco-api-1.0.5 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Does anyone know how to handle this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `monad-logger` package started to export the `Loc` symbol starting with version `0.3.4.0`. This version isn't excluded by the Cabal file of `fpco-api`.

You could try

```
cabal install fpco-api --constraint="monad-logger < 0.3.4"
```

to force using an older version of `monad-logger`.

---

More explanation about the error:

The module `FP.Server.Types` in the package `fpco-api` defines a datatype `Loc` that's used throughout the package. The module `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax` defines a *different* datatype `Loc`. This modules isn't used directly by `fpco-api`, but `fpco-api` makes use of the `monad-logger` package, which in turn uses `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`. That's no problem as long as at no point in the program, both different `Loc` types are in scope. But in its most recent version, `0.3.4.0`, the `monad-logger` package decided to re-export the `Loc` datatype from `Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax`. Now in many places where the logger monad is imported in `fpco-api`, suddenly both `Loc` types are in scope, and GHC doesn't know to which one the local occurrences of `Loc` refer.

The proper fix for this error is for `fpco-api` to be hiding the `Loc` re-export from the logger monad, or to explicitly refer to the right one by using qualified names. But this requires a source code update of `fpco-api`. The temporary fix to use an older version of `monad-logger` should hopefully be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it to look at results. But I don't quite understand the reasons of the error :)

Comment: @RottenBrain Ok, I've added more details :)